# Traversal of Complex Data Structure in a Rails Application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, iteration, tree-traversal

I have a data structure in which Topics have subtopics, which again have subtopics,  continuing down from the original Topic about six levels. Each of these topics has multiple subtopics.
I'm looking for a way to traverse this data and bring back data affiliated from each of the subtopics... as if pulling the data I want "downstream".

```
For example Given a topic structure:
Harry_Potter > Characters > Slitherin_House.videos
```

(Assuming that slitherin house has subtopics for each of the members, Malfoy, Crabbe, etc. )  I want the videos for each of the members to appear in the video lists for Slitherin_House, Characters, and Harry_Potter (each of the ancestors).

I've been looking around and stumbled across [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/%22Ancestry%22) and [Acts As Tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree/%22Acts%20as%20Tree%22) and read through the code and tried my hand at using them, but they seem more oriented around the ancestor side of things, as opposed to accessing and pulling data from the children.

I also have tried my hand at using the associations

```
 has_many :through, and has_and_belongs_to_many
```

but have been unsuccessful in my attempts to create a working traversal system. And can't seem to complete wrap my head around how to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on what to do given such a predicament? Or know of gems which provide for any such functionality?

Relationship class & model: (as it should flow like a stream)

```
class CreateStreams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :streams do |t|
      t.integer :downstream_id
      t.integer :upstream_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :streams, :downstream_id
    add_index :streams, :upstream_id
    add_index :streams, [:downstream_id, :upstream_id], unique: true
  end
end





# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: streams
#
#  id            :integer         not null, primary key
#  downstream_id :integer
#  upstream_id   :integer
#  created_at    :datetime        not null
#  updated_at    :datetime        not null
#

class Stream < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :downstream_id

  belongs_to :subsidiary, class_name: "Topic"
  belongs_to :tributary, class_name: "Topic"

  validates :downstream_id, presence: true
  validates :upstream_id, presence: true

end
```

Topic Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: topics
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#  slug       :string(255)
#  wiki       :string(255)
#  summary    :string(255)

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  attr_accessible :name, :wiki, :summary

  has_many :streams, foreign_key: "downstream_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tributaries, through: :streams, source: :tributary
  has_many :reverse_streams, foreign_key: "upstream_id",
                             class_name:  "Stream", 
                             dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :subsidiaries, :through => :reverse_streams, source: :subsidiary


  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 },
                   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  def downstream?(other_topic)
    streams.find_by_downstream_id(other_topic.id)
  end

  def flow!(other_topic)
    streams.create!(downstream_id: other_topic.id)
  end

  def dam!(other_topic)
    streams.find_by_downstream_id(other_topic.id).destroy
  end
end
```

Note: I  also want to be able to assign a subtopic, multiple parents. So that characters could potentially get put underneath of "Actors" as well for example.

Comment: Can you show the source of your models and tables?

Comment: Added Topic Model, and Stream(Relationship) Model/table

I can add the Topic Table as well though it is spread over multiple migrations so I added the annotated version

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set this up in a simple way i'd go for a recursive relation. This means a topic can belong to another topic (nested)

The database model of the topic would look like:

Topic

- id
- topic_id
- title

the model would then be:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :topics
end
```

Now if you have a topic. you can access its parents by doing `.topic` and its childs with `.topics`. A Topic with no parent is a toplevel one and a Topic with no childs is a end node.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I also want to have multiple parents which is why i was going after the has_many :through and h_a_b_t_m data models.